# Ubuntu 18.04 - problem with sound & alsamixer

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

I've got problem with sound on my fresh-installed Ubuntu 18. Every time when I boot my laptop sound is muted and there is no option to turn up the sound. My sound settings look like this:

[image: click]

After few hours I've discovered that there is way to fix it. In Alsamixer settings:

[image: click]

I need to unmute the Headphone and turn it up to 100%. Problem is that alsamixer forget those new settings after every reboot. It's really exhausting to set it every time when I turn on my computer. Is there way to fix it? I suppose that alsamixer shouldn't recognise my built-in speakers as headphone. How can I change it?

Comment: I have a similar issue. What is your soundcard model?